# How does the concentration of a reactant change? Is it based on individual order or overall order?

Tags: kinetics

Reaction $\ce{A + B ->[$k$] C + D}$ follows the rate law $$r = k [\ce{A}]^{1/2}[\ce{B}]^{1/2}$$ where $k$ is given. Starting with $1 \,\pu{M}$ of $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{B}$ each, what is the time taken for concentration of $\ce A$ to become $0.1 \,\pu{M}$? Do we use the integrated law expression of first order (overall order) or half order (order w.r.t. $\ce{A}$)?

Comment: In this special case, r=k.[A]

Comment: Why? What’s special in this particular rxn?

Comment: It is not about chemistry, but simple algebra. $x=y \implies x^{1/2}y^{1/2} = x$. // As $[\ce{A}] = [\ce{B}]$

Answer (score 0):

*At High School Level 
The order of a Reaction is the  Sum of powers of concentration terms in The Rate Law Expression. Therefore, acc. to the rate law expression provided in the question $$r = k[A]^{1/2}[B]^{1/2}$$ The order of Reaction is 1. 
 Let the Concentration of reactants at any point of time during reaction $$\ce{ A +B→C +D}$$ be $xM$ 
 Now the rate law becomes $$ r = k x $$ 
  Now you can integrate the rate law obtained as usual.

Comment: I think the correct transformation follows a similar patter as the second order reaction, i.e. $\frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} t} = -k\sqrt{(A_0-x)(B_0 -x)}$, where $A_0$ and $B_0$ stands for the initial concentrations.

Comment: But it is given that bot reactants start witl $1M$ comcentration. And you would get the same results from you equation any my equation if the limits in integration are put properly.